# Scrapy extract element text with "<" symbol?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am scraping a page that has temperature data and the fields contain "<" and ">" symbols to describe the ambient temperature. These aren't encoded in the HTML so when I extract them using a selector the element text is truncated at the symbol. As one might expect this is only a problem with the "<" symbol. Ideas on how to get around this? I POST the scraped data as JSON to my API - in case that complicates matters. Code:

```
t = temps.xpath('td[@class="temperature_am"]//p/text()').extract()
```

HTML:

```
<p>Temperatures are normal (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).</p>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on klettier's answer: replace `"< "` with `"&lt; "` (note the space in each of those) in the input HTML.

```
var cleanedHtml = html.Replace("< ", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("< "));
```

In a quick test I ran, three major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, and Safari) all treated `<` as a literal when it was followed by a space (even if that space was followed by an element name, e.g. `a`). So it would make some sense that the web page you're scraping would take that liberty, even though the HTML spec says that authors "should" use `&lt;` instead of `<`.
But I'm a little surprised that scrapy doesn't follow the same convention as those browsers.

According to the [HTML language reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-start-tags), a `<` at the beginning of an actual element start or end tag cannot be followed immediately by a space.

Comment: P.S. if you have a `<` that's not followed by a space, but needs to be treated as a literal, show us the context.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I see is to clean the Html before loading it into HtmlDocument.

```
var html = @"<html><body><table><tr><td class=""temperature_am""><p>Temperatures are normal (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).</p></td><tr></table></body></html>";
var cleanedHtml = html.Replace("(<", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("(<"));
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(cleanedHtml);
var innerText = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//td[@class='temperature_am']")
                                .ChildNodes
                                .First(s => s.Name == "p")
                                .InnerText;
var text = httpUtility.HtmlDecode(innerText);

Assert.Equal("Temperatures are normal (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).", text);
```

Comment: Thanks @Integrateur but the "<" symbol can occur anywhere in the text, not just after a "(".

Comment: You have to find a pattern to isolate the text to replace by its equivalent in HTML. Like HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Regex.Matches(@"<html><body><table><tr><td class=""temperature_am""><p>Temperatures are normal (< 4 degrees C / < 40 degrees F).</p></td><tr></table></body></html>",@"\((.+)\)")[0].Value)

Comment: @MoreScratch: if < can appear *anywhere* in the text, it's indistinguishable from the beginning of a tag, and the HTML is theoretically unparseable. But if the literal < always appears before a space, you could replace "< " with "&lt; ".